# Serialize and Compress class to file

Tags: c#, filestream, deflatestream

I am trying to write a class to a file and open the class from a file. This works for me; however, the file size is very big. (65 MB, compressed in a .rar is 1MB).

This gave me the reason to think that I could compress the data before writing to the file.

My original functions are;

```
public static void save(System system, String filePath){
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

    try{
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, system);
        fs.Flush();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        fs.Close();
    }
}

public static System load(String filePath){
    System system = new System();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

    try{
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        system = (System)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Flush();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        fs.Close();
    }

    return system;
}
```

To compress I Tried the following, however this does not seem to work correctly when loading to the system class:

```
public static void save(System system, String filePath){
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

    try{
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        DeflateStream cs = new DeflateStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress);
        bf.Serialize(cs, system);
        fs.Flush();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        fs.Close();
    }
}

public static System load(String filePath){
    System system = new System();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

    try{
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        DeflateStream ds = new DeflateStream(fs, CompressionMode.Decompress);
        system = (System)bf.Deserialize(ds);
        fs.Flush();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }finally{
        fs.Close();
    }

    return system;
}
```

Am I using the DeflateStream incorrectly? What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using `DeflateStream` wrong in your `save()` method. You have to either wrap it in `using()` or explicitly call `Close()` for it to finish its job.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense. Never used the DeflateStream before!